# Fetching File from Assets not Working with Angular Server Side Rendering

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I am loading a `json` file from the assets folder at runtime with the following code:

```
initializeApp = () =>
  new Promise(async resolve => {
    this.settings await this.http.get(`/assets/file.json`).toPromise();
    resolve();
  });
```

This code works fine when compiling the angular app with `ng serve`. However I also want to support [server side rendering](https://angular.io/guide/universal). When building the server with `npm run build:ssr` and afterwards running it with `npm run serve:ssr`, I get the following error on the node server:

```
ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
    at resolvePromise (/project/services/frontend/dist/server.js:1003:31)
    at /project/services/frontend/dist/server.js:913:17
    at rejected (/project/services/frontend/dist/server/main.js:136313:93)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/project/services/frontend/dist/server.js:542:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (/project/services/frontend/dist/server/main.js:118689:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/project/services/frontend/dist/server.js:541:52)
    at Zone.run (/project/services/frontend/dist/server.js:301:43)
    at /project/services/frontend/dist/server.js:1061:34
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/project/services/frontend/dist/server.js:574:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (/project/services/frontend/dist/server/main.js:118670:33)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using angular universal, URL must be absolute. So either have the base URL in your configuration somewhere, or retrieve it from the underlying webserver like shown in the  [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/universal#using-absolute-urls-for-server-requests)

Answer (score 0):

In server side add resolve or reject because your promise is not handle by any resolver or reject.

Comment: I am already calling `resolve()`. I also tried to add a `try catch` with a `reject`, but it didn't help

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood me, but adding `resolve` or `reject` did not fix the issue. But I appreciate your help :)